# What happened to the activity icons and nested sequences in my UiPath Studio project, and how can I bring them back?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

One of my UiPath Studio projects got messed up somehow. Many of the activities now show a generic rectangle instead of their normal icon. The While loop below (#1) is missing its nested sequence completely.

Even less affected activities are missing UI controls. For example, For Each (#2) has no textbox for specifying which collection to iterate over. Instead it just has a label that reads *In String*.

Is there a way to fix this? There many workflows in this project, so it would be ideal to avoid migrating to a new project if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading your packages.

You may be using prerelease package versions that are incompatible with your version of Studio. Downgrading them to the latest stable versions may resolve the issue.

1. Click *Manage Packages*
2. Uncheck *Include Prerelease*
3. For each package that ends in *-preview* (except where you're sure you want the prerelease version):

   - Click the package
   - Select the latest non-prerelease version
   - Click *Update*
4. Click *Save*

Studio should restore the non-prerelease versions of the dependencies at this point, and your project should start displaying correctly again.